# OSGi headless deployment on Linux

Tags: eclipse, deployment, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I've developed a OSGi application on my windows machine that is just lovely. How ever I need it to run on my Linux server and this is where I run into problems.

My application has no GUI. It simple works with a console and is command line driven.

My first attempt at deployment I built a product based on my existing run target. It exported fine to a Windows .exe so I added the required delta packs for Linux. The problem with this is it has only two options Linux (GTK) and Linux (MOTIF). My linux server runs on CentOS with no GUI as it is a hosted machine so when I try and deploy it I get a segmentation fault.

I have been searching around as to what to do but I'm not coming up with any answers.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have been banging my head on this one for over a week

Cheers

Comment: You mean it SEGVs when you try and run it on your server?  What if you pick Linux/GTK, but then start it using `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar -application my.headless.application` ?

Comment: @paul-webster I COULD KISS YOU, YOU BEAUTIFUL MAN! I've been banging my head on this for 2 bloody weeks and all I needed to was was add an -application paramter

Comment: @artbristol -1 for "How ever"? Haha just joking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google keyword you need is 'xvfb' - it acts like an X server, but ignores everything sent to it, so you don't need any graphics hardware. Try firing that up (make sure you set `DISPLAY` appropriately).

A cleaner solution would be to figure out why the library is demanding an X server if it works without - perhaps you could update the question with more details.

Comment: I'll have a look into 'xvfb' thanks. Although I was really hoping to work out how to export the product with some kind of headless environment rather then having to try and alter my Linux

Comment: I'm puzzled by this one as well. If it's headless Java code then you shouldn't have to make any effort to get it to run in a headless environment. But then you talk about delta packs and GTK and it's all rather confusing. What are you really trying to do? Are you *sure* your code is headless and doesn't try to create a GUI?

Comment: I agree with you Neil. When I export my product to windows it makes a nice .exe that just pops up a console.

However when exporting to Linux there are only 2 options Linux GTK or Linux Motif. There should be no need for either of these but I am guessing that is why I get a segmentation fault when I run it on linux

Comment: Explain what you mean by 'exporting'

Comment: In eclipse I create a new "Product Configuration". This defines all the bundles that I want and their starting area.

In the Product Configuration Editor window there is a button 'Eclipse product export wizard' or you can get to this via File->Export->Eclipse Product

In export wizard your able to define where you want the files created. It has a check box 'export for multiple platforms' by selecting this the next screen shows the available platforms such as  Win(x86), Linux(GTK), macosx(carbon/ppc) and a few others.

Comment: I am a rather linux novice. Could it be a different issue? I have no idea how to debug a segmentation fault. I upload the application to a standard user home directory. I chmod the eclipse file to make it executable, try and run and bang. Segmentation fault

Comment: You might be targeting the wrong platform. What's the output of `file [executable]` vs `uname -a`?

Comment: uname -a = Linux 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 18:43:13 EST 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: file eclipse = eclipse: ERROR: error reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: However the file is there. I chomd 777 to make it executable

Comment: I suspect you're "exporting" far more than your application actually needs. If you include a bunch of GUI plug-ins then you will get a GUI, and this fails... and it's nothing to do with your own bundles. Why not just build the bundles? Eclipse's "export" mechanism is quite unstable, unreliable and unrepeatable.

Comment: Very good point Neil. The export function dumps all my plugins as JARs into a plugin directory. I'll try manually installing them and starting them. This will be quite tedious as bundles have to start in a defined order. Do you know if its possible to some how run like a Run target?